# Sprite example from AndEngine's example project, looks pixelated when imported to my own project

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, andengine

I'm trying out AndEngine (GLES2) in the last couple of days.
I'm having a problem with the SpriteExample from the Examples project.
In the SpriteExample in the example project the face_box.png sprite looks nice and sharp.
However when I copy the same code and the face_box.png file to my own separate project, the sprite looks pixelated.

Since the code is just the same I guess the problem is with some configuration settings, however I could not figure it out.

I'm running on Galaxy S2 with ICS.

Does anyone have any idea on what might cause the problem?

This is the code if anyone wondered -

```
public class AndEngineMapActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity implements OnClickListener {
// ===========================================================
// Constants
// ===========================================================

private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

// ===========================================================
// Fields
// ===========================================================

private ITexture mTexture;
private ITextureRegion mFaceTextureRegion;

// ===========================================================
// Constructors
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Getter & Setter
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
// ===========================================================

@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

    return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_SENSOR, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
}

@Override
public void onCreateResources() {
    try {
        this.mTexture = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
            @Override
            public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                return getAssets().open("gfx/face_box.png");
            }
        });

        this.mTexture.load();
        this.mFaceTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(this.mTexture);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Debug.e(e);
    }
}

@Override
public Scene onCreateScene() {
    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

    final Scene scene = new Scene();
    scene.setBackground(new Background(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));

    /* Calculate the coordinates for the face, so its centered on the camera. */
    final float centerX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mFaceTextureRegion.getWidth()) / 2;
    final float centerY = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mFaceTextureRegion.getHeight()) / 2;

    /* Create the face and add it to the scene. */
    final Sprite face = new Sprite(centerX, centerY, this.mFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    scene.attachChild(face);

    return scene;
}

@Override
public void onClick(final ButtonSprite pButtonSprite, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(AndEngineMapActivity.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

// ===========================================================
// Methods
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Inner and Anonymous Classes
// ===========================================================
```

}

**Update: ** Following to JoenEye's advice I tried loading the texture differently with

```
@Override
public void onCreateResources() {
    try {
        this.mTexture = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
            @Override
            public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                return getAssets().open("gfx/face_box.png");
            }
        }, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);

        this.mTexture.load();
        this.mFaceTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(this.mTexture);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Debug.e(e);
    }
}
```

The results have improved and the smiley face picture looks a bit better, but it's still not as sharp as in the Example's project.

****Another Update: ****

These are the images of the results I get.
 - 
This is the one from the original example project (best result)
[image: This is the one from the original example project (best result)]
This is the one from my project without the TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA
[image: This is the one from my project without the TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA]
This is the one from my project with the TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA (current result
[image: This is the one from my project with the TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA (current result]

By the way way - Interesting result, once I created another empty project with only this class in it and it worked flawlessly and looked good.

So I guess it must be some kind of a configuration problem with my own project.

I'd be glad to get any more ideas!

Thanks!

Comment: You are using a strange way of loading the image, I have never seen that before in AndEngine. Anyway, you probably didn't set proper TextureOptions. I do it in the constructor of BitmapTexture - new BitmapTextureAtlas(1024, 512, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA). Your version of AndEngine is be different, so your implementation may be different.

Comment: Thanks JohnEye I followed your advice with the BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA and the results have improved. But it's still not perfect because the same example on the examples project looks much sharper. I also tried the other option such as only Bilinear or NEAREST, but Nearest only made it worse, and Bilinear only looked exactly like BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA. Anything else I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I decided to just open up a new project and move all my code to the new project.

It works.

I know it's a bad solution, but it solved the problem.

If I'll ever come up with this problem again, and find a real solution, I would update it in here.

Answer (score 2):

I'll guess that the difference between the example project and the one with the bad result is either the subpixel location of the sprite or it being stretched/skewed slightly. Are you careful to draw the sprite exactly on a pixel boundry?

The issue is when a fragment is drawn, if the fragment is not perfectly lined up with the texture it is sampling, then it must generate a color that is not exactly what is in the texture. For example if you have a 10x10 pixel texture, and you draw it at screen coordinates (0.5, 0.5), then each pixel either needs to just pick the nearest texel (`NEAREST` sampling), or blend together nearby texels (`LINEAR` or `BILINEAR` sampling). `NEAREST` can have rounding problems here if two texels are equal distances from the sample point (which might explain the slightly ugly image in the first bad result). If you use `LINEAR` sampling, then it just blends together the nearest texels, which may give the slightly blurred image you see in the second result.

So to remedy this for small images with tiny features, you want to always make sure to draw the image so that it lines up exactly with a pixel boundry. Can you check if you are doing this in your application?

For more information I would do some google searches for 'pixel perfect sampling/rendering`, which will give you more information.

EDIT, I also noticed this, which may explain:

```
final float centerX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mFaceTextureRegion.getWidth()) / 2;
final float centerY = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mFaceTextureRegion.getHeight()) / 2;
```

You're doing integer division here, which could cause you to get the value of 'center' off by a half pixel if the image width/height is an odd number. Then when you pass this value to AndEngine your center is incorrect by a half pixel, explaining the subpixel problems.

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for the response! Yeah I figured something with the pixels not being aligned perfectly may be the problem, but I still can't understand why.I tried changing x and y values to fixed values like 400,400 or 0,0 but it still didn't help. However sometime there was a slight improvement if I changed it to 399.5f for example, but still not good enough. I tried changing the theme of the xml layouts of my activities but it was no good too.I simply got no idea how this could have gone badly.Maybe you got any more ideas?I also tried compiling it to 4.0.3 instead of 2.2 but it was no good.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't think of anything else. I don't know enough about andEngine to know what it's doing under the hood. Maybe try their forum if you don't find an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the standard way of loading images unless the method you use is necessary for some reason.

```
mTexture = new BitmapTexture(1024, 512, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
BitmapTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(mTexture, this, "face_box.png", 0, 0);
```

You will probably end up using buildable textures that place the images on the texture automatically, but this could help you determine where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it seems like we may not work on the same API. When I try to copy your code the compiler complains on both lines - he says that there's no such BitmapTexture constructor that accepts these parameters and it doesn't recognize "BitmapTextureRegionFactory". I'm using GLES2, so maybe that's why?   Also, the reason I'm using this method to load the texture is only because it's in the examples project and besides it I don't know any other method. Any chance I'm doing something wrong? Thank you very much nonetheless.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I didn't mention that you should use equivalent code from your version. It could be BitmapTextureAtlas, or you need slightly different parameters. Try BitmapTextureatlasTextureRegionFactory. There is a combination that works with your version of AndEngine, you just might have to dig into the source code or see what the IDE you use suggests. Why this was in the example I don't know, unless something dramatically changed in GLES2, the preferred way of loading images is similar to my example.

Comment: Hey again, I tried it again with this code - BitmapTextureAtlas a = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 32, 32, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
   a.load();
   mFaceTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(a, this.getAssets(), "gfx/face_box.png",0,0); It don't think it affected anything :/ It seems like maybe the sprite or the camera doesn't work on even pixels or something like that, and therefore the picture distorts. Got any more ideas?

Comment: Not really. Could you please post some screenshots? It may help us see what the problem is.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, try replacing ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_SENSOR with ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE. Probably won't help, but it doesn't hurt to try.

Comment: Hi again JohnEye, I tried changing the ScreenOrientation to LANDSCAPE_FIXED but it didn't help. I updated the question and added the pictures. Maybe you could figure something out. Thanks a lot for trying so far!

Comment: Well, I'm sure I haven't seen that kind of problem yet. From the edit it seems you're onto something, so I hope you will be able to figure it out. Since the code is obviously not to blame, I would look at AndroidManifest.xml and/or run Project->Clean (Assuming you work in Eclipse).